# Javascript: How to fill an array on every possible way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations

I have an array of length 16 and I need to get every possible combination of elements within a range from 0 to 256. More precisely, I need the following arrays

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
...
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,256]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
...
[256,256,256,256,256,256,256,256,256,256,256,256,256,256,256,256]
```

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Two nested cycles?

Comment: That's a lot of arrays... 257^16?

Comment: @MinusFour: I know ;-) wostex: I don't see it how..

Comment: `I know ;-)`  Wow, what computer do you have that could process this, I want one..

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iterating function like this:

```js
function next(array, max) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    array[i]++
    if ((array[i] %= max) !== 0) break
  }
  
  return array
}

let array = Array(3).fill(0)

do {
  console.log(next(array, 3).join())
} while (array.join('') !== '000')
```